# Where in Switzerland can you refill a gas cylinder?

Tags: food-and-drink, switzerland

Are there any shops / facilities where man can get a gas canister refilled in the Switzerland (around Chur)? I am interested in filling a 2kg gas canister like the one on the picture.

[image]

I know that it is possible to buy / change a gas canister at various gas stations but the cylinders sold in the Switzerland do not fit to our stove. Our stove is attached directly on the top of the canister but canisters I have seen here in Switzerland have a valve that points sideways.

Comment: Can you please add more information on the kind of gas canister you own and want to have refilled? It might be that if the kind of sale are not suitable for you, yours might not be suitable for their filling stations.

Comment: Will [this canister](https://www.bauundhobby.ch/Baumarkt/hobby-%2b-sport/outdoor-trekking/kochen-geschirr-k%c3%bchlen/kartuschen/weber-gas-kartusche/C08030206/P4173701/de) fits your stove? if so, then it's available in the nearest Coop supermarket chain..

Comment: I thought the usual approach was to exchange an empty one for a full one, rather than refill an empty one.

Answer (score 1):

Your tank is likely proprietary to the Czech Republic (perhaps available in some neighboring countries), so not something you will likely find further away in Switzerland.

If by some chance, the threads and valve on your tank match the threads and valve on the Swiss tanks (other than position), perhaps a refilling station can refill the tank.  But most countries are pretty strict about tanks, refilling, etc.

Comment: @pnuts - If there are no places you can bring your tanks for refilling, then I suppose that "if/perhaps" would be a "no can do".  It has been a while since I dealt with camping gas in Europe.